# Android 11 - Default Text Messaging App - SMS button not showing for some contacts

Tags: sms, google-messages

On Android 11 - Default messaging app:

When I type some text, "SMS" appears under the send button for some contacts but not others.

Just curious as to why.

Contact 1:

[image: Contact 1]

Contact 2:

[image: Contact 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google messages app says text message sent by SMS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232098/google-messages-app-says-text-message-sent-by-sms)

Comment: Removed Android 11 tag, since this feature isn't restricted to 11