# Does WiFi calling also send SMS over data lines?

Tags: wi-fi, sms, calls

Our only carrier in this area gives us one bar at home due to thick brick walls. I read that Android supports WiFi calling. This has helped phone call quality immensely. Does SMS also get sent via our WiFi so they are reliably sent as well?

Comment: Yes. If you are using Google messages app configured for that https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232098/131553

Comment: From what I know this seems to be carrier specific, on some networks SMS seems to work, on some you can only send and on some it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Any reason or tell-tale signs whether SMS texts will come through via Wifi Calling? Would such activity be an item outside of (not included in) the typical mobile plan, a technological loophole?

Comment: @user610620 You send a text to your smartphone where there is very weak mobile data  but has WiFi calling turned on using a phone that has better mobile data signal on a  different network.